# Editable Text Over Image

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering, is there a way of getting text to go over an image, but have it so that the text can be changed without going into the html, aka using a textbox from a form displayed on the webpage, and the inputted text being put on the image? i know it can be done but im struggling on where to start, and any reply pointing me in the right direction would be most gratefully recieved.

Gareth

Comment: is there an live example or an mockup-image of what you are trying to achieve? what do you mean by "image over text"

Comment: Did you try styling an `<input type="text">` with a transparent background and no border?

Comment: "image over text" "way of getting text to go over an image." Which do you want? Your question makes almost no sense.

Comment: that should state "text over image" sorry, i dont have any mockups or live examples

Answer (score 3):

If browser compatibility is not an issue, this can be done with HTML5 like so:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

Then you could either set the image as the background image for that div, or place the image within that div but set the z-index lower than that of the text.

Comment: I had no idea about the `contenteditable` attribute. Seems to work great in Chrome: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gqhG/).

Comment: good, but i ideally need it via a form box, i understand it can be done in imagick, but was wondering if it could be done any other way